# Sticker extension with external source

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, imessage

I want to add an iMessage Extension to my existing app to offer custom sticker. 
First I did:

> Xcode > File > Add Target > IMessage Extension

Then, I found some url of picture that I could use as test sticker.

And my controller looks like this :

```
import UIKit
import Messages

class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController, MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource {

    var stickers = [MSSticker]();
    var url = ["http://iconizer.net/files/Brightmix/orig/monotone_close_exit_delete_small.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Japan_small_icon.png"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        print(" ----- HERE");

        loadStickers();
        createStickerBrowser();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Stickers Handling

    func loadStickers() {

        print(" ----- loadStickers");

        for i in 0...1 {
            do {
                let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: URL(string: url[i])!, localizedDescription: "\(i)")
                print(" \(i) : \(sticker)");
                stickers.append(sticker)
            } catch {
                print("error \(error)");
            }
        }
    }

    func createStickerBrowser() {

        print(" ----- createStickerBrowser");

        let controller = MSStickerBrowserViewController(stickerSize: .large)

        addChildViewController(controller)
        view.addSubview(controller.view)

        controller.stickerBrowserView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        controller.stickerBrowserView.dataSource = self;

        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: controller.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    // MARK: - MSStickerBrowserViewDataSource

    func numberOfStickers(in stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView) -> Int {
        return stickers.count
    }

    func stickerBrowserView(_ stickerBrowserView: MSStickerBrowserView, stickerAt index: Int) -> MSSticker {
        return stickers[index]
    }

    // MARK: - Conversation Handling

    override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the extension is about to move from the inactive to active state.
        // This will happen when the extension is about to present UI.

        // Use this method to configure the extension and restore previously stored state.
        print("----- willBecomeActive");
    }

    override func didResignActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the extension is about to move from the active to inactive state.
        // This will happen when the user dissmises the extension, changes to a different
        // conversation or quits Messages.

        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers,
        // and store enough state information to restore your extension to its current state
        // in case it is terminated later.
        print("----- didResignActive");
    }

    override func didReceive(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when a message arrives that was generated by another instance of this
        // extension on a remote device.

        // Use this method to trigger UI updates in response to the message.
    }

    override func didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the user taps the send button.
    }

    override func didCancelSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
        // Called when the user deletes the message without sending it.

        // Use this to clean up state related to the deleted message.
    }

    override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
        // Called before the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

        // Use this method to prepare for the change in presentation style.
    }

    override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
        // Called after the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

        // Use this method to finalize any behaviors associated with the change in presentation style.
    }

}
```

I'm not seeing any of my print and the background color is ok but I can't see my stickers.
Apple doc says this :

> fileURL A URL for the image displayed by this sticker. This URL must
>   refer to a file saved on the device. The file must be a PNG, APNG,
>   GIF, or JPEG, and must be less than 500 KB. For the best results, the
>   image should not be smaller than 100 x 100 points or larger than 206 x
>   206 points. Always provide @3x images (300 x 300 pixels to 618 x 618
>   pixels). The system generates the @2x and @1x versions by downscaling
>   the @3x images at runtime.

So do you know a way to save locally picture downloaded from a server?

Answer (score 0):

Just save downloaded image using extension (png or jpg).
On my example, I saved png files on location of discardable cache files (Library/Caches)

```
[...]/Library/Caches/StickerCache/Pack_1188767/image_166176391.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add normal and animated sticker to an existing app.

Add a new target and select "Sticker App Extension". Unfortunately you have to scroll to see this option.

"iMessage Extension" is the right choice, if you want more than just stickers, e.g Interactive iMessage Apps.

[image: New Target Dialog]